# session_start(): Function spl_autoload_call()

Tags: php, session

I am getting this message on going to several pages:

Warning: session_start(): Function spl_autoload_call() hasn't defined the class it was called for in /var/www/library/session/session.php on line 18

This is the file that is creating the calls:

```
        <?php
        namespace iX\session;

        class session{
            private static $instance;
            private static $init=false;
            private static function doFirstInit(){
                ini_set('session.name', \iX\config::get('system')->session->name);
                ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', \iX\config::get('system')->session->cookie->lifetime);
                ini_set('session.cookie_path', \iX\config::get('system')->session->cookie->path);
                ini_set('session.cookie_domain', \iX\config::get('system')->domain->name);
                ini_set('session.use_cookies', ((\iX\config::get('system')->session->cookie->use)?'1':0));
                ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', ((\iX\config::get('system')->session->cookie->onlyCookies)?'1':0));
                \iX\core::load('library/session/interface.php');
                \iX\core::load('library/session/handler/'. \iX\config::get('system')->session->handler.'.php');
                $class = '\iX\session\handler_'.\iX\config::get('system')->session->handler;
                $class::getInstance();
                session_start();
                self::$init = true;
            }
            public static function getInstance(){
                if(!self::$init)
                    self::doFirstInit();
                if(!(self::$instance instanceof session))
                    self::$instance = new session('main');
                return self::$instance;
            }
            private $handler=array();
            public function __construct($handler){
                $this->handler = &$_SESSION[$handler];
                if(!isset($this->handler['userid'])) 
                    $this->handler['userid'] = 1;
                if($this->handler['userid']==0)
                    $this->handler['userid'] = 1;
                if(!isset($this->handler['counter'])) 
                    $this->handler['counter'] = 0;
                if(!isset($this->handler['login'])) 
                    $this->handler['login'] = false;
                if(!isset($this->handler['numpages'])) 
                    $this->handler['numpages'] = 0;
                if(!isset($this->handler['lock'])) 
                    $this->handler['lock'] = false;
            }
            public function __get($name){
                $this->handler['counter']++;
                return (!isset($this->handler[$name]))?false:$this->handler[$name];
            }
            public function __set($name,$value){
                if($this->lock==false){
                    $this->handler[$name]=$value;
                    return true;
                }else return false;
            }
            public function __isset($id){
                if(isset($this->handler[$id]) && $this->handler[$id]!=null) return true;
                return false;
            }
            public function __unset($id){
                $this->handler[$id] = null;
                return true;
            }
            private function __cleanup(){ 
                $this->handler = array(); 
            }
            public function getPages(){ 
                return $this->numpages; 

            }
            public function setIncreasePage(){ 
                $this->numpages++; 

            }
            public function Login($uid){
                $this->login=true;
                $this->userid = intval($uid);
                $this->userId = intval($uid);
            }
            public function setLogout(){
                foreach($this as $key=>$value)
                    $this->{$key} = null;
                $this->role = "guest";
                $this->userId = 0;
                $this->login=false;
            }
            public function isLogin(){ 
                return $this->login; 
            }
            public function isRlogin(){ 
                return ($this->rActive == true && isset($this->rLogin))?true:false; 
            }
            public function cleanup(){ 
                $this->__cleanup(); 
            }
            public function put(){ 
            }
            public function lock(){ 
                $this->lock = true;  
            }
            public function unlock(){ 
                $this->lock = false;  
            }
            public function get_stat(){ 
                return $this->lock;  
            }
            public function rewind() { 
                reset($this->handler);  
            }
            public function current() { 
                $var = current($this->handler); 
                return $var;  
            }
            public function key() { 
                $var = key($this->handler); 
                return $var;  
            }
            public function next() { 
                $var = next($this->handler); 
                return $var;  
            }
            public function valid() { 
                $var = $this->current() !== false; 
                return $var;  
            }
            public function __toString(){
                $return = '';
                foreach($this->handler as $key=>$value) 
                    $return .= $key.':'.$value."\n";
                return $return;
            }
            public function __toArray(){ 
                return $this->handler;  
            }
            public function toString(){ 
                return $this->__toString();  
            }
            public function toArray(){ 
                return $this->__toArray(); 
             }
            public function getSession(){ 
                return $this->handler;  
            }
            public function restoreSession($session){
                $session = unserialize($session);
                    if(is_array($session)) 
                        $this->handler = $session;
            }
        }
```

How can I get rid of this Warning. I don't just want to disable the warning calls. I want to have a clean app.
Please somebody enlight me.

Chris

Comment: It means your autoloader function can't find a class you're trying to use.  Try to add a little debug echo to your autoloader to see what file paths it's trying.

Comment: the only method that uses autoload is smarty so far. The autoloader is planed for the next step

Comment: I'm using propel orm for database abstraction. I don't know if the use spl, but I'll check this

Comment: it's solved. Looking for the spl call was really helpfull. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    // ...
```

and the best solution will be:

in `index.php`.

Comment: Well, can't really do this, cause I'm using my own session handler. So the session start can only be called if all pre required libs are loaded